# Multiple scoped has_many through relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, has-many-through

I want to model such a relationship between the models User and Event.

[image]

Therefore I have started with the following classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
# with columns user_id and event_id
...
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, :through => :attendances
  ...
end
```

So far everything is okay: I can assign users and access attendances. But now I want to bring the state into play, such that I can distinguish e.g. between "attending", "unexcused absent", ... users. My first try was:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, :through => :attendances
  has_many :unexcused_absent_users, -> { where :state => 'unexcused' },
                                   :through => :attendances,
                                   :source => :user
  ...
end
```

(:source has to be specified since otherwise it would search for a belongs to association named 'unexcused_absent_users')
The problem here is, that the where-predicate is evaluated on table 'users'.

I am clueless how to solve this 'correctly', without introducing new join tables/models for every state. Especially since every user can be just in one state for every event, I think a solution with one Attendance-model makes sense.

Have you an idea, how to get this right?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply narrow the scope to look at the correct table:

```
  has_many :unexcused_absent_users, -> { where(attendances: {state: 'unexcused'}) },
                               :through => :attendances,
                               :source => :user
```

Evem better, add this scope to the Attendance model and merge it in:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.unexcused
    where state: 'unexcused'
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :unexcused_absent_users, -> { merge(Attendance.unexcused) },
                               :through => :attendances,
                               :source => :user      
end
```

Comment: Using merge with a named method in the `Attendance` class is clean. Unfortunately this won't work though.  The `Event` class is missing an association named `attendances` and for some reason the association will be readonly. I have no idea why, but when saving through it the `state` set in the scope is lost/ignored/nil.

Comment: @MarioZigliotto: "The Event class is missing an association named attendances..."  - The OP had written in the initial code that `Event` contained the line `has_many :attendances`.  Can you explain what you mean?  In the solution given by the OP, he refers to `:user_attendances` - perhaps the association name was changed?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround, but I still think, this is ugly.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_attendances, :class_name => 'Attendance'
  has_many :users, :through => :user_attendances, :source => :user

  has_many :unexcued_absent_user_attendances, -> { where :state => 'unexcused'}, :class_name => 'Attendance'
  has_many :unexcused_absent_users, :through => :unexcued_absent_user_attendances, :source => :user
end
```

In general: For every state that I want, I have to introduce a new has_many relationship with a scope and on top of that and an according has_many-through relationship.

Comment: I ran into a very similar issue and have since logged an issue on the Rails project (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10945).  I'm not 100% sure it's a real issue or user error on my part but I ended up doing a similar workaround as you.  Using this workaround I encountered some strange stuff.  For example, I would bet that doing something like this: `Event.create!(title: 'foo', unexcused_absent_user_ids: [1,2,3])` results in the `state` attribute being set to `nil`.  If you want to bump my issue on github or have any further feedback on your approach i'd love to hear it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used that example `Event` creation because I think it's very similar to what the `EventsController#create` might receive as a POST from a page where the user is adding an Event and simultaneously flagging the people who had unexcused absences. (i.e. like a bunch of checkboxes with student names)

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, :through => :attendances

  def unexcused_absent_users
    User.joins(:attendances)
      .where(:state => 'unexcused')
      .where(:event_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

in rails 3+ methods are basically the same as scopes, just less confusing (in my opinion), they are chainable

```
event = Event.find(xxxx)
event.unexcused_absent_users.where("name LIKE ?", "Smi%")
```

Comment: This has the drawback, that this is not writable. And adding another method `unexcused_abent_users= array` is not that "railsy" in my opinion :\

Comment: the method `unexcused_abent_users` above returns an `ActiveRelation` object not an array; having the 'stateful' collection be writable doesn't seem like a good idea to me? you could use specific methods to change the state i.e. `event.absent_but_not_excused!(user)` or `user.not_excused_from(event)` - guess it comes down to personal preference